# Search for Name by #hashtag in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am developing with Ruby on Rails, want to know whether there is an efficient way to find a name matches a hashtag.

Input:  `#annrobinson`

if there is a record name `"Ann Robinson"`, it matches

if there are other records, like `"Ann Robin Son"` , `"Annro Bin son"`, they fulfill the requirement too.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are spaces your only factor in the search?

Comment: I am considering space characters \s in regex, but dealing with space is a good start

Comment: Suppose User is your model. Then you can get it by User.where("CONCAT('#',LOWER(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))) = ?", '#annrobinson')

Comment: Exactly, thanks Bachan!

Comment: Welcome David, I am adding it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose User is your model. Then you can get it by

```
User.where("CONCAT('#',LOWER(REPLACE(name, ' ', ''))) = ?", '#annrobinson')
```